# Cannot print repositories declared in settings.gradle using custom task in build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle and I'm trying some stuff out.

I have the following settings.gradle file:

```
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

rootProject.name = 'minimal-example-buildsrc'


dependencyResolutionManagement {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url <some-url>
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER")
                password = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PWD")
            }
        }
        maven {
            url <some-url>
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER")
                password = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PWD")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I declare two repos in the settings.gradle file. Then I have a build.gradle file (in the same folder as the settings file, this is a single-project build):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


task listRepos {
    doLast {
        println "Repositories"
        project.repositories.each {println it.name}
    }
}
```

When I run the task:

```
./gradlew listRepos

> Task :listRepos
Repositories

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 813ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

you can see that the repos don't print. This changes if I declare the repos in the build.gradle file. Why can't I see them when I declare them in the settings.gradle?